Script.Util.HttpRequest automatically retrieving content of redirect page
We have a process where the unsubscription of a certain product are handled via a csv which is dropped in the FTP, then imported in a data extension and finally processed by a script.
In this script we build a url to perform the unsubscription via a GET request which returns a 301 HTTP code.
In this script depending on the value of the "Location" header we treat the unsubcription as a success or a failure.
Here is the piece of code:
    var URL = 'https://google.com/'
    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(URL);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 0;
    req.continueOnError = false;
    req.emptyContentHandling = 1
    req.contentType = "application/json";
    req.encoding = "UTF-8";
    req.method = "GET";

    var resp = req.send();
    Platform.Response.Write(resp.content);
    Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(resp.headers));
    Platform.Response.Write(String(resp.headers["Location"]));

Lets use as an example http://google.com, if you check the network tab of the chrome dev tools, it returns a 301 HTTP code with the value "https://www.google.com/" in the Location header.
But SSJS does not returns the content and headers of the first API call, we noticed that the content and headers of the response are the ones from the final page "https://www.google.com".
Does anyone know if there's a way for the request not to follow the redirection or should we ask the backend team to develop a POST mehtod as well (there's already one but secured using HMAC which we were unable to create using SSJS)?
Thank you

Possible XY Problem. Why would you not want to follow a permanent redirect (301)? Please edit your question and describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Added context, hope it helps
